# Class pass by reference and thread

Tags: c#

I have code below, I pass `attachment` object to `SendMessage` method. The problem is that `SendMessage` is in another `thread` and when `SendMessage` try to use `attachment` the `attachment` is already destroyed because Objects is passed as reference by default. What would be best solution for this problem?

```
var attachment = new Attachment(fileStream, fileName);
new Thread(() => MailHelper.SendMessage(message.Mail.Headers.From.Address, "EmailConvertSuccess.txt", attachment)).Start();
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a separate thread?

Comment: To not block main thread while sending e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection works across threads, so that should not be the problem.

Do you dispose of the source `FileStream` (or wrap it in a `using` block)? Then that's probably the problem, because the file stream is already disposed when you try to access it.

The exact exception message would help in finding out exactly where the problem is.